# Building the Scheurman's Model II constraints for a multi period linear program

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, scheduling

[Scheurman's paper](https://academic.oup.com/forestscience/article-abstract/23/suppl_1/a0001/4675760?redirectedFrom=fulltext) discusses Model I and model II Formulation to solve harvesting and scheduling problems. It is a specific implementation to solve multi period linear programs. Both models are also shown in [this paper](http://faculty.washington.edu/toths/Publications/McDill_etal_M2.pdf), if you can't access the first.

I'm trying to understand how to build the model II by hand and reimplement them in a computer program. I am getting stuck on equations (12), (13), (16), and (17) on page 14 in what they mean and how to "write them down" of the second paper that I've linked to.

Comment: Hi, may I ask what language you are using to code the models? And what have you tried? The first point is quite relevant to get a proper answer to the question.

Comment: I'm using Python, pulp, and numpy. That being said, I am trying to solve it on a piece of paper first. I'll share what I have later on today.

Comment: @dassouki, to add dhasson comment, do you have any experience to write the mathematical model before that?

Comment: @A.Omidi yes I do. But for this one, I'm having trouble 'understanding' the rationale behind the equations